Why my second navbar does not work on mobile phone?
So, my site does not work on mobile phones. When the user scroll with the finger the site does not scroll, stay static. That happen when I create a second navbar responsive (super simple) with only css, Its a simple responsive nav bar, without hamburger, requested by the company to be like this:


.menu-h ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr); /* 9 cells in the grid, of same width */
  gap: 1rem; /* gap between 2 cells of the grid */
  max-width: 1600px;
  min-height: 57px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.menu-h ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align the box of <a> horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* align the box of <a> vertically */
  text-align: center; /* alithe the text of <a> */
}

.menu-h ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #483e3e;
}

.menu-h ul li:hover {
  /* hover of <li> so that the effect is performed on the cell of the grid */
  background-color: rgb(166, 232, 57);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(19, 83, 57);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-h ul {
    display: none;
  }
}

.menu-h1 ul {
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    9,
    1fr
  ); /* 9 cells in the grid, of same width */
  gap: 1rem; /* gap between 2 cells of the grid */

  max-width: 1600px;
  min-height: 57px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.menu-h1 ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align the box of <a> horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* align the box of <a> vertically */
  text-align: center; /* alithe the text of <a> */
}

.menu-h1 ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #483e3e;
}

.menu-h1 ul li:hover {
  /* hover of <li> so that the effect is performed on the cell of the grid */
  background-color: rgb(166, 232, 57);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(19, 83, 57);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-h1 ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-h1 ul li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
<nav class="menu-h1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">GoodCaring</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Saúde e Higiene Sénior</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Logística e Indústria</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Soluções de embalagem</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Agricultura</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Gestão de Resíduos</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Artigos de Celulose</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Artigos de Higiene e Limpeza</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Embalagens Biodegradáveis</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="menu-h">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">GoodCaring</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Saúde e Higiene Sénior</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Logística e <br />Indústria</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Soluções de embalagem</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Agricultura</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Gestão de <br />Resíduos</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Artigos de <br />Celulose</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Artigos de Higiene e Limpeza</a></li>
    <li><a href="catalogo.php">Embalagens Biodegradáveis</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



I try to change the margins, the display, but no... Nothing works.
I know it's from the second navbar because the backup of the site (when the navbar is not responsive) everything works.

I tried it on my iPhone and everything seems correct, I can normally scroll. add missing elements to the snippet if required to reproduce the issue.
